# Node.js: Workaround for calling methods when an object isn't done initializing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm working on upgrading a library that looks something like this (in coffeescript for conciseness):

```
//machine.coffee

exports.Machine = class Machine
  constructor: (config) ->
    /** initialize Machine with config data **/

  getSomething: (callback) ->
    /** do something that depends on config **/
    callback null, something
```

and is used like you might expect:

```
machine = require 'machine'
config = {knob: "tweak", switch: "fiddle" }

myMachine = machine.createMachine config

myMachine.getSomething (err, something) ->
  /** we now have something **/
```

However, now the config is dependent upon a setting that I have to request from another site, so it looks more like this, and Machine was updated to parse and use the data from external sources. So accessing Machine like this works:

```
config = {knob: "tweak", switch: 'http://returns/switch/data' }

/**methods now must wait until Machine is initialized with remote config data **/
machine.createMachine config, (err, machine) ->
  machine.getSomething (err, something) ->
     /** we now have something **/
```

But the problem is this breaks the original usage which was:

```
myMachine = machine.createMachine config

/** remote calls to config not completed yet **/

myMachine.getSomething (err, something) ->
  /** we don't have something because Machine is still initializing **/
```

My question: Is there anyway to preserve the original use case?
One approach might be to queue method calls on the uninitialized class until its fully initialized, but I'm not sure how to even begin doing that.  Is there even a way to queue methods? Or are there other better approaches that would allow legacy code with the original usage to still work?

**Clarification**:
I have no control over the initial `config` data nor over when or what methods will be subsequently called on Machine. I do have the ability to modify Machine in any way necessary though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should expose a `Machine` constructor anymore. Rather, you should expose an async factory function:

```
class Machine # not exported
    # ...

exports.createMachine = (config, cb) ->
    getConfig(config, (err, configData) ->
        if err return cb(err)

        cb(new Machine(configData))
    )
```

Comment: Oops, yes, this will work, and it's essentially what I have now, but the issue I run into is how to prevent subsequent method calls to Machine (which is under user control) from failing because they occurred before the new Machine was fully initialized.

Comment: If you use this, the user never gets a non-initialized machine, because you don't export the constructor and you only pass out machine instances in an async callback.

Comment: Yes, but the user has to use the callback result, which is a change for them. What I'm trying to think through is there a way to call a method on Machine, without having to wait until it's initialized (but after initialization started). I like your answer, but it's breaking existing implementations.

Comment: If your API is changing to require asynchronous initialization, then at some point you're going to need a breaking change to introduce asynchronicity. If all of machine's methods were async already, then there is a solution; is that the case?

Comment: Marked this one best as it's the cleanest approach, even though it introduces a breaking change to the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could pull the remote calls out into a function that fills `config`. Then you could move `machine.createMachine config` and the `getSomething` call into a callback that gets called after `config` is completely filled out.

That way your `machine` doesn't have to know anything about the remote sources or how to parse their data.

Comment: The main issue I have is that in the original usage, I don't see config until it's provided as part of `machine.createMachine`. Once I do see it, I don't have any visibility into when or what subsequent methods would be called on machine. However, I might not be fully comprehending your meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow the problem. getSomething() is already async, right? So presumably the implementation of getSomething() is already deferred and returns execution.

If, otoh, you don't have an internal deferral mechanism, i.e. you were previously relying on deferral being provided by another library like a database driver that gets built in your constructor, then you'll need to build your own deferral mechanism.

The simplest form I can think of, off the top of my head would be something like:

```
exports.Machine = class Machine
  constructor: (config) ->
    @deferred = []
    initialize (err, @magic) => 
      @ready = true
      def[0].apply( @, def[1] ) for def in @deferred

  getSomething: (callback) ->
    if @ready
      @magic.getSomething (err, stuff) -> callback( stuff )
    else
      @deferred.push [@getSomething, arguments]
```

In a nutshell: if you can't do it yet, remember what it is you were trying to do in a log, and then just return. Later, when you're ready to do those things, loop through the log and go back to where you were, to pick up where you left off.

Comment: Thanks, I've been experimenting with something similar, the issue with this approach is that any calls to getSomething before Machine is initialized return `undefined`, but the methods do eventually get executed, which might work for my use case.

Comment: Well, yah; Deferred functions shouldn't return return anything: you expect their results to show up in the callback. I assumed from your original signature that they were already functioning that way?

At worst, a deferred function could return a handle of some sort to potentially allow continued communication with the request. You could cancel a deferred function, for instance, if you returned something that could be used to identify the request later. Unless the request is really resource intensive though, it'd likely be easier to just change the behavior in your callback instead.